# Why does Java truncate the preceding is in JSON responses?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I have a spring rest API that returns a JSON response from the response class shown below:

```
public class myResponse {

private String anyString;
private boolean isBoolean;

//getters and setters
}
```

I am expecting the JSON response to be:

```
{
"anyString" : "foo",
"isBoolean" : true
}
```

However, whenever I inspect the browser for the response obtained, I get:

```
{
"anyString" : "foo",
"boolean" : true
}
```

Why is the preceding "is" being truncated?

Comment: java and javascript and different things. Make sure title and tags tally.

Comment: Most likely your getter for `isBoolean` also named `isBoolean()`. This means whatever the library that deserializes the response will infer the property name as just "boolean", because this is the default per Java Beans convention. You'll need to qualify the property name if you want different behavior. Since no further info on the case is given, I can not give further details.

Comment: What are the names and access for the getter for isBoolean (ie are they public)?

Comment: You need to tell us which library actually performs the conversion. It’s not the language itself that does anything, JSON is not build into Java.

Comment: @JGFMK the access modifiers are isBoolean() and setIsBoolean(boolean b)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Spring Boot, then somewhere internally it uses Jackson to transform your object into json string.

you can dive into the logic of ObjectMapper class, but the idea is that it follows [JavaBeans convention](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch06_02.htm) for accessing fields and getting resulting naming.

So, for boolean property named 'isSth' (via method object.isSth() ) actually represents a field 'sth' for json. If you want to strictly set the name of the field in json, use @JsonProperty annotation